# R: Statistic/Computational efficiency

Tags: performance, r, matrix, distribution

What my chunk of code is doing is to fill up a 4X100000 matrix with either T of F. 
lets name the matrix X. then Xij ~ Bernoulli(P) and P~normal(0.5,0.15) where max(P) = 1 and min(P) = 0.

The statistic is very inefficient. If there is a distribution that the above process adhere to please help me also.

The computation is very slow, because i have to fill up the entire matrix 1 entry by 1 entry, which each time being random. Is there a way to reduce the time taken significantly? It is extremely inefficient.

**Statistics efficiency problem here**

```
x = rnorm(100000,mean = 0.5,sd = 0.15)
x[x > 1] = 1
x[x < 0] = 0

probability = function(x){
  x.sam = sample(x,1)
  p = c(x.sam,1-x.sam)
  return(p)
}

aggro2 = function(x){
  aggro2 = sample(c(T,F),1, prob = probability(x))
  return(aggro2)
}
```

**Computational efficiency problem here**

```
ptm = proc.time()
aggro =c()
n=100000
for (i in 1:(4*n)){
  cat(round(i/(4*n)*100,2),"\n")
  aggro = c(aggro, aggro2(x))  
}
aggro.mat = matrix(aggro,4,n)

elapsed = proc.time()[3] - ptm[3]
cat(elapsed)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this?

```
system.time({
    x <- rnorm(400000,mean = 0.5,sd = 0.15)  ## pick normal variables
    x2 <- pmin(1,pmax(0,x))                  ## bound at 0 and 1
    mids <- which(x2>0 & x2<1)
    x2[mids] <- rbinom(length(mids),prob=x2[mids],size=1)  
    res <- matrix(x2,ncol=4)
})
```

This doesn't seem to be exactly the same as what you're doing, but it seems (?) to match your description.

elapsed time: 0.443 seconds

Several of the things that you're doing will be unnecessarily slow:

- using a `for` loop instead of vectorizing
- creating a vector by appending instead of allocating the whole vector and then replacing elements
- printing in the course of the `for` loop

Comment: +1 Great (and fast) answer. Took me a little while to understand it. Clever use of pmin and pmax and also not unnecessarily sampling random variates with a probability of 1 and 0!

Comment: the distribution of the binomial doesn't fit, but otherwise just brilliance! thx!

Comment: what do you mean by "the distribution of the binomial doesn't fit"? `rbinom(n,prob,size=1)` is a sample of `n` Bernoulli trials with probability `prob` ... which is what I thought you wanted

Comment: @TanEugene when n = 1 (as you have here) the binomial distribution *is* a Bernoulli distribution

Comment: indeed each element is a bernoulli, but when you have n as the number of observation and size being the number of trials, what the rbinom(n=400000, size = 1, prob = vector) does is just have the probability of success of each trial being the first value of the probability vector. which is the same as just rbinom(n,size, prob = vector[1]).

Comment: that's not true! `rbinom` is vectorized over both `size` (irrelevant in this case) and `prob`.  Do you have evidence to the contrary?

Comment: to better explain, what i really require is a rbinom(n=...,size =1,prob) type of function, where by the prob parameter is the probability of success on each observation, not trial.

Comment: @BenBolker, run your code ample times, say 5000-10000 times, storing the probability of success sum(res)/400000 each time. then the mean of the prob will approach 0.5, but the standard deviation will approach 0

Comment: @TanEugene That's because you actually calculate the standard error this way, i.e., sd/sqrt(n).

Comment: @Roland i don't understand how is sd() performing sd/sqrt(n)

Comment: The standard error is the sd of the means. If you draw an infinite number of samples, the sd of the sample means will approach zero.

Comment: thank you roland, cleared it all up. sry, but for my future usage, could someone help me understand why rbinom(n=..., size = 1, prob = vector) would use the vector to propagate each observation rather than each trial as stated in help?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking. `rbinom(5,1,0.5)` does 5 coin flips (takes 5 independent samples of size 1) and reports the result of each coin flip.

Comment: vector = c(0.5,0.8,0.9) rbinom(n = 3,size = 1,prob = vector) seems to be doing 3 coin flips with the first coin flip being a success with prob 0.5 and the last coin flip being a success with prob 0.9, but in ?help, it states that prob is the prob of success on each trial (which is size)

Comment: You are misreading this. `rbinom(2,2,c(0.5,0))` will use p=0.5 for "each trial" needed to produce the first observation and p=0 for "each trial" needed to produce the second observation.